# Vb Error object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: vb.net

I'm having issues creating an updater for my program. It just gives me this error when pressing the button :

object reference not set to an instance of an object

I have a dll file and a Forms application file.

Here is the code of the dll file:

```
Public Class Class1
Dim bit As Boolean = False

Sub bits()
    'For 32 and 64 bit decison
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists("C:\Program Files(x86)") = False Then
        bit = False
    Else
        bit = True
    End If
End Sub
Sub CheckFolder(ByVal i As String)
    If i.Contains("Program Files") And bit = False Then
    ElseIf bit = True Then
        i.Replace("Program Files", "Program Files(x86)")
    Else
    End If

    If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(i) Then
    Else
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(i)
    End If
End Sub
Sub downloadupdate(ByVal location As String)
    My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/e872b78tgcw3pbv/update.txt?dl=1&token_hash=AAFCqEhjemoPI2iKjvv3LbzfuwJ1Gd-G1Kb-Xcebef7tig", location)
End Sub
Sub checkupdate(ByVal location1 As String)
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(location1) = True Then
        Dim update As String
        update = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(location1)
        If update = My.Application.Info.Version.ToString Then
            MsgBox("No updates found!")
        Else
            MsgBox("Updates Found!")
        End If
    Else
        downloadupdate("C:\")
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

And here is the code for the actual form:

```
Imports Updates.Class1
Public Class Form1
Public download As Updates.Class1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    download.bits()
    download.CheckFolder("C:\")
    download.downloadupdate("C:\")
    download.checkupdate("C:\")
End Sub
End Class
```

The DLL File is imported as a referance to the Forms Application
But it gives me that error
Please, Any help?

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace or a line number for where the error is occurring?

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the class object with the `New` keyword.

```
Public download As Updates.Class1
```

Should be:

```
Public download As New Updates.Class1
```

Comment: Now it says "The given file path ends with a directory separator character."

Comment: For the root drive I don't think you need the path separator.